# FileNotFoundException catch error when reading from file in Java

Tags: java, file, input, output

I am trying to write a simple program that reads integers in from a text file and then outputs the sum to an output file. The only error I am getting is in my catch block at line 38 "Unresolved compilation problem: file cannot be resolved". Note that "file" is the name of my input file object. If I comment out this exception block, the program runs fine. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadWriteTextFileExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int num, sum = 0;

        try
        {
            //Create a File object from input1.txt
            File file = new File("input1.txt");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

            while(input.hasNext())
            {
            //read one integer from input1.txt
                num = input.nextInt();
                sum += num;
            }
            input.close();  

        //create a text file object which you will write the output to
        File output1 = new File("output1.txt");
        //check whether the file's name already exists in the current directory
        if(output1.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("File already exists");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(output1);
        pw.println("The sum is " + sum);
        pw.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException exception)
    {
        System.out.println("The file " + file.getPath() + " was not found.");
    }
    catch(IOException exception)
    {
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
}//end main method
}//end ReadWriteTextFileExample
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope in Java is based on blocks. Any variable you declare inside a block is only in scope until the end of that same block.

```
try 
{ // start try block
    File file = ...;

} // end try block
catch (...) 
{ // start catch block

  // file is out of scope!

} // end catch block
```

However, if you declare `file` before your `try` block, it will remain in scope:

```
File file = ...;

try 
{ // start try block


} // end try block
catch (...) 
{ // start catch block

  // file is in scope!

} // end catch block
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. This first part was actually given by the professor so I think I'll just draw an arrow moving the line above the try block. I'm not sure if this was a mistake or if we were supposed to catch it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `file` variable is declared within the `try` block. It's out of scope in the `catch` block. (Although it couldn't happen in this case, imagine if the exception were thrown before execution had even reached the variable declaration. Basically, you can't access a variable in a `catch` block which is declared in the corresponding `try` block.)

You should declare it *before* the try block instead:

```
File file = new File("input1.txt");
try
{
    ...
}
catch(FileNotFoundException exception)
{
    System.out.println("The file " + file.getPath() + " was not found.");
}
catch(IOException exception)
{
    System.out.println(exception);
}
```